# ¿ Se puede hacer excepciones para los mensajes de advertencia de brew doctor?

Tags: macos

Todo funciona correcto en mi sistema y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de hacer una excepción para que brew doctor pase por alto la advertencia que me genera, y la próxima vez no la muestre, tengo brew y miniconda instalados pero no me generan ningun error tenerlo asi por eso quiero crear una excepción para la advertencia de brew doctor porque es molesto... o que me recomiendan hacer ?

```
bomberMan ~ $ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
    /Users/AndyMC/miniconda2/bin/python-config
    /Users/AndyMC/miniconda2/bin/python2-config
    /Users/AndyMC/miniconda2/bin/python2.7-config
```

Comment: Pues las advertencias son solo avisos. En el primer párrafo puedes leer exactamente lo que estás pidiendo: _si todo funciona bien: no te preocupes e ignóralas_.  Aunque el consejo que da tiene bastante sentido y _deberías_ considerar la posibilidad de hacerle caso. Además `brea doctor` se ejecuta _cada corpus y San Juan_.